# I'm getting a memory leak error in my own substr function

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

```c
char *ft_substr(char const *s, unsigned int start, size_t len)
{
    size_t  i;
    size_t  d;
    char    *subs;

    i = 0;
    d = 0;
    subs = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

    if (!subs || !s)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    while (s[i])
    {
        if (i >= start && d < len)
        {
            subs[d] = s[i];
            d++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    subs[d] = '\0';
    return subs;
}
```

The code that appears above is the substr function I wrote, when I checked the memory leak using [Memd](https://github.com/bibhas2/Memd), I noticed that there was an error on the 14th line.

`subs = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));`

Unfortunately, I do not have the authority to install Valgrind on the device I use, so I was able to test with memd. I'm fairly new to C, can you explain why I'm getting a memory leak error and how can I fix it?

Comment: It will leak if you pass a `NULL` pointer, because you have already allocated for the new string. It can't be `free`d later because the pointer was forgotten. You can fix it by testing `s` first.

Comment: You got too clever with trying to do all your error checking in one `if` statement, and introduced a bug.  Per, IIRC, Peter van der Linden:  "Clever code is bad code."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to solving this would be to add a guard to the beginning of your function, *before* you allocate for `subs` which may never be returned and thus be unable to be freed.

```
if (!s) return NULL;
```

You can still check later when `subs` is allocated and return `NULL` if that allocation fails.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code in order to write better and use my other functions. I gave up on doing all the queries with a single `if` and the problem went away. I refactored the code using `strlen` and `strlcpy`.

Comment: @EnesKutlay what if start > strlen(s)

Answer (score 1):

```
subs = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
if (!subs || !s)
{
    return (NULL);
}
```

I the sub-statement of the if statement will get the control when s is equal to NULL when there will be a memory leak.

Pay attention to  that you may remove the check whether s is a null pointer as all C standard string functions do. If the user will call the function passing a null pointer then there will be undefined behavior.

And the call of malloc can allocate more memory then it is required.

Also the types of the second and third parameters are inconsistent.

```
char    *ft_substr(char const *s, unsigned int start, size_t len)
```

The both should have the type `size_t`.

Comment: It's an exercise given by this school, I don't decide how I should define function. Therefore, you can ignore the definition.

Comment: @EnesKutlay If you may use the standard string function strlen then use it to determine how much memory to allocate for the substring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it safe you need not only to check if `s` is not NULL but also if the start is not past the length of the string.

Try to have only one return point from the function and rather use positive checks (ie if something is valid, instead of checking if it is invalid).

```
char *ft_substr(char const * restrict s, const size_t start, const size_t length)
{
    char  *subs = NULL;

    if(s)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(s);
        if(len >= start)
        {
            subs = malloc(length + 1);
            if(subs)
            {
                char *wrk = subs;
                size_t tocopy = length;
                s += start;
                while(tocopy-- && (*wrk++ = *s++));
                *wrk = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return subs;
}
```

Comment: Whether a substring starting at or beyond the end of the string should be `NULL` or an allocated empty string is debatable and should be part of the specification.

Comment: `while((*wrk++ = *s++) && tocopy--);` will copy one byte too many. You should write `while (tocopy-- && (*wrk++ = *s++)) continue;`

Comment: @chqrlie good spot :) . p1. it is debatable but it has to be checked anyway